# Adobe Air iOS - FileOffset error

Tags: ios, flash, adobe-air

Boas, eu estou actualmente a desenvolver para iOS em Adobe Air em modo de distrubuição Ad-hoc.

Estou a usar actualmente estas tecnologias:

- Adobe Air 18
- Adobe Flash Player 17
- Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
- Adobe Flash Profissional CC 2015

Quando vou publicar o meu ipa com os meus assets aparece-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode-me ajudar a perceber este erro? Como posso resolver?

Obrigado por qualquer informação ou ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei por perceber o que limite máximo para o iOS em assets é de 6GB.

A outra razão para a mensagem de erro, deve-se ao facto de que o iOS não gosta de swf com frames inacabadas na timeline.

[image: Errado]

O método acima está errado e deve ser corrigido na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto faz sentido visto que no meu caso ao fazer distribuição ad-hoc, e passar por AOT Mode, o compilador ao meter os assets com abc code, num single file como o ipa entrava em erro, depois de já ter sido submetido um stop nas últimas frames.

O erro ainda não é bastante claro e não existe referências sobre o mesmo no adobe forums.

Espero que isto ajude alguém no futuro.